# iOS: UIKit - Images / Buttons / Pages in UIPopoverVIew

Tags: ios, uikit, popover

I have some quite simple questions but it's hard to find an answer for them ;)

The images are from Apple's Numbers app:

**Image 1)**

How do they put this 4 split on the top of the `UIPopover` in place?
How do they put the 2 split - buttons ("2D/3D") inside the `UIPopover`?
How is it possible to have several (6) images in there that work as clickable items?

And the last question: How to mix all this with a table view - the "Chart Options" seems to be a table view cell.

**Image 2)**

It's quite like in the first one that there are different images to select but this time it has multiple pages which is quite exactly what I need. Hints for copying this would be awesome :)

I just need to know what to look up - how to copy exactly this layout.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples, Apple is probably using a `UIViewController` inside of the `UIPopoverController`. They can then do anything you would usually do inside of a `UIViewController` - like add the `UISegmentedControl` you asked about.

For your question about how the 'toggles' are put into the top of the popover, Apple probably has the view controller enclosed in a `UINavigationController`. They then set the `titleView` property of the navigation bar to a `UISegmentedControl`.

The grid of images in the picture is probably a `UICollectionView` in pair with a `UIScrollView` with `paging` turned on.

> **Disclaimer:**
>
> I don't have any connection with the team at Apple that built Numbers, and therefore have only the app itself to infer what they did from. Unless someone *from Apple* steps forth and tells (which they won't), we don't know for sure what they did.

Comment: Hey thank you for giving me all the names of the classes I can have a look into! But how did apple put the UICollectionView inside the UIViewController? After the collection view it goes on like the UICollectionView was an entry in the table view.

Comment: @Max If the collection view is indeed inside of a table view, then Apple probably built a transparent UITableViewCell with the collection view inside and a UIPageControl at the bottom.

Comment: That was more related to the first image - there you can see it clearly. When do you use UIScrollView and when UIPageControl in this scenario?

Comment: Those are for the second image - the page view is the little dots underneath the collection view.

Comment: Hey, no worries I will mark the answer as correct that helped me the most to come to a solution after I coded it :)

Comment: @Max Thanks :) I'd love to see what you come up with when it's done, too!

Comment: Hey, I'm not done yet. It's quite hard to make 15 items per page to work and I still don't know how to set the page control and so on. But your advice brought me so much furhter that your answere deserved to be ticked :)